# Unir distintos csv de distinto tamaño de datos en uno solo con python

Tags: python

Tengo distintos archivos csv y todos tienen escrito solo la primera columna, pero tienen diferente tamaño. Por ejemplo un archivo puede tener en una columna 100 datos y otro archivo puede tener en esa columna 35. Entonces me gustaría 'meter' cada csv en una columna distinta de un mismo archivo. ¿Es posible?

Comment: ¿Cómo se llenan los valores que faltan? ¿Se deja vacío, se pone cero, se reproduce el último valor?

Comment: Dejo vacía las celdas que falta, ya que luego estaré trabajando en el excel con diferentes formulas matematicas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En esta solución definimos una función `junta_csv` que recibe el nombre del archivo de salida a generar y una lista con los archivos de entrada.

Los archivos de entrada son .csv de una sola columna, con una primera fila de encabezado. Se toman los encabezados de cada archivo de entrada para formar el encabezado del archivo de salida.

Los archivos de entrada pueden ser de distinto largo. Si un archivo se agota antes que los demás, se procede como si se leyeran una línea en blanco.

Respecto a la implementación, la lista `handles` contiene los archivos de entrada (file object). Cuando el archivo se agota, la posición se reemplaza con `None`.

Se ocupa la función `any` para revisar si queda algún archivo abierto. La función examina la lista y retorna `True` si hay al menos un valor distinto de `None` en la lista.

```
def junta_csv(salida, archivos):
    """
    Crea un archivo .csv a partir de multiples
    archivos .csv con una sola columna

    :param salida: Nombre del archivo de salida.
    :param archivos: Lista de archivos de entrada.
                     Son .csv con header en la primera fila.
    """
    # La lista handles contiene el file object de los
    # archivos abiertos. Al agotarse el archivo, la
    # posición es reemplazada con None
    handles = [] # Archivos de entrada
    headers = [] # Headers de cada archivo de entrada
    #
    #   Abrir los archivos de entradas, leer los headers
    #
    for arch in archivos:
        file_handle = open(arch, "r")
        handles.append(file_handle)
        headers.append(file_handle.readline().strip())
    #
    #   Procesar los archivos de entrada hasta agotarlos
    #   todos.
    #
    with open(salida, "w") as out:
        #   Formar la primera linea con los headers de
        #   las columnas.
        header = ",".join(headers)
        out.write(f"{header}\n")

        #   Cuando se acaba un archivo, asignamos None
        #   en su posición dentro de handles; por tanto
        #   mientras haya un handle distinto de None,
        #   seguimos iterando.
        while any(handles):
            fila = []
            #   Leer una fila de cada archivo para
            #   formar una fila de salida.
            for index in range(len(handles)):
                celda = ''  # Valor por default para la celda.
                if handles[index] is not None:
                    dato = handles[index].readline()
                    if dato:
                        celda = dato.strip()
                    else:
                        #   Se agotó este archivo.
                        handles[index].close()
                        handles[index] = None

                fila.append(celda)

            if any(handles):
                #   Grabar la fila de salida.
                salida = ','.join(fila)
                out.write(f"{salida}\n")

    #   Cerrar archivo de salida
    out.close()
```

**Demo**

Probamos con estos cuatro archivos de entrada

arch1.csv

```
Sequencia
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
```

arch2.csv

```
Valor
11
12
13
14
15
16
```

arch3.csv

```
Credito
1.1
2.2
3.3
```

arch4.csv

```
Opcion
a
b
c
d
e
f
g
i
j
k
```

*Código*

```
archivos = ["arch1.csv", "arch2.csv", "arch3.csv", "arch4.csv"]
junta_csv("salida.csv", archivos)
```

salida.csv

```
Sequencia,Valor,Credito,Opcion
1,11,1.1,a
2,12,2.2,b
3,13,3.3,c
4,14,,d
5,15,,e
6,16,,f
7,,,g
,,,i
,,,j
,,,k
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me ha servido! Estoy comparando este código y el anterior para analizarlos y entenderlos para saber el procedimiento. Muy amable